# How to record this drawing effect?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I think this effect can be done with Blender grease-pencil.

I understand 3D tracking camera and object.

But how to record the drawing process in Blender?

Comment: Your question is alredy pritty good. You can even improve on it to edit your question in a way that it fullfills the last criteria of a good question https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . And accept answers that solved your question.

Answer (score 13):

After using the greas pencil to create your drawing, you can use the build modifier to animate the draw-in along the stroke.

[image: draw in effekt grease pencil build modifier]

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the grease pencil objects are fully 3D, so you have to create the drawing, track the camera, render on a transparent background (a sequence of PNG images) and composite them onto your live footage.

[image]

You can also create a 3D mesh and use it as surface, to guide your strokes, enabling "surfaces" as stroke placement.

[image]